# All Audio frequencies

Tags: c#, c++, audio, visualization

How can I get(Is it possible?) all audio frequencies are now playing in the system for writing some sound visualizer? Is there any library c++ or c#?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic steps are:

- apply window function to block of samples (e.g. 1024 samples, Hanning window)
- perform real-to-complex FFT on windowed samples
- take magnitude of each FFT output bin (`sqrt(re * re + im * im)`)
- identify peaks in resulting power spectrum estimate
- the bin index of each peak corresponds to the frequency of that component

Comment: These are basic steps of what action?

Comment: @TGadfly: these are the basic steps for determining the frequency components present in your audio stream. You can use an FFT library such as FFTW or KissFFT to do the heavy lifting - the rest is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but i think you can use [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/) library to do that. Specifically, [Get spectrum](http://www.fmod.org/docs/HTML/FSOUND_DSP_GetSpectrum.html) function.