# How I estimates power spectral density (PSD) using FFT in C#?

Tags: c#, fft

I used Math.NET for FFT but I dont know how estimate PSD. I found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/psd-estimate-using-fft.html) solution only for Matlab.

Comment: The link you gave show pretty good example using `fft` to get the `PSD`. You just need to translate it to C# I think...

Comment: See: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2613009/253056) and other similar questions (seach for "power spectrum", "spectrogram" or "periodogram").